# JSON object mapping - map ID to actual objects

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am loading JSON data and mapping it to java objects.  I am on Android platform, using GSON currently, but open to switching to other libraries if necessary.

The JSON contains some objects that link to other objects. For example: a restaurant object has an id to a category object, which is also in the JSON data:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "fast food"
    }
  ],
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "name": "McDonalds",
      "category": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

That works out great so far. However, in the Java class that represents the restaurant instances, I'd like to include a Category field directly, i.e.:

```
public class Restaurant {
    public String name;
    public Category category;
}
```

Rather than having to do something like this:

```
public class Restaurant {
    public String name;
    public int category;

    public Category getCategory() {
        Category category = ... // logic to obtain Category object from a category id

        return category;
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do, and if so, how could I go about doing it?

Comment: It is a good practice to separate the Object from network requests and the Domain object. Then have a mapper to translate one to another. This is not the answer you want, but IMHO it's a better solution.

Comment: will Category have a fixed list of values?
Is it an enum perhaps?

Comment: @BMacedo the answer I want is the best/most correct/easiest to maintain answer, so I will look into what you have said.

Comment: @Manza No, that information should be allowed to change.  It is part of the JSON data itself, so it's entirely variable on what is delivered to me.

Comment: @BMacedo is that "good practice" design pattern have a name/information I can look up?

Comment: You should make the "server-side" to the heavy work, if at all possible. Why return back an "ID" that you have to lookup later? Just nest the `"category": {}` object straight into the JSON

Comment: @Zach The idea is to decouple the domain objects from code related to specific frameworks. Also, to keep each class with only one reason to change. Will you change your domain classes each time the server decides to add, remove or rename some field in some request? I follow Robert Martin's advice in that regard. For some example, look into his description of [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)